# vueが立ち上がってくれない

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

https://github.com/hands-lab/En-Gyo-Neo

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

goとmysqlは立ち上がるのですがvueが立ち上がってくれません

参考にしたもの

- https://qiita.com/po3rin/items/c70105f684e6816621d2
- https://qiita.com/yu-croco/items/0c0d5083298f7db9e1bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

修正ポイントが2つありそうです。
1. docker-composeのvueにてcommandを指定していますが、Dockerfileの内容と被りますし、yarn installは不要だと思います。そもそもの行自体が不要で、これを消した上で下記の修正をDockerfileに適用したら動きました。
2. docker/client/Dockerfileにて、最後に `CMD yarn serve` を追記します。これで、shellで引数としてコマンドを指定しなくてもよくなります。

余談ですが、yarnはyarnだけでyarn installと同じ挙動になったはずです :)

Answer (score 1):

実行した結果以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

`docker logs en-gyo-neo_vue_app_1`

```
yarn run v1.10.1
$ vue-cli-service serve
/bin/sh: vue-cli-service: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

エラー本文に記載されている通り、vue_appイメージの中で `vue-cli-service` というコマンドがインストールされていないためエラーが発生して終了してしまっているようです。

Comment: yarn でinstallしているんですけどね